# Does Scala .flatMap( ) .flatten( ) Disintegrate the top level collection or the bottom level collection

Tags: scala

In the case of List(List(1, List(2)), List(List(3), 4)).flatten:

I assumed in the order of operations, we go to:
List(1, List(2)) List(List(3), 4)

And combine the two loose elements into:
List(1, List(2), List(3), 4)

In other words, the outermost wrapping is disintegrated first. This appears to contradict the assertion [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-flatmap-method/), which says "the inner grouping of an item is removed and a sequence is generated".

Which, if either, is technically correct?

Comment: Your lists contains two elements, that are also lists. These lists are what is referred to as "inner grouping", they are removed, so you get a sequence of the (ungrouped) elements from those two lists. There is no contradiction.

Comment: You have result which is `F[F[A]]` for some `F[_]` and some `A`. Here: `F[_] = List[_]` and most likely `A = Any` since inner list contain both `Int`s and `List[Int]`. `list.flatten` takes all elements of this `list` - they have to be lists as well! - and then all their elements and creates a new `List` containing these elements. It's not universal intuition since you could implement `flatten` for e.g. `[Element] =>> (FixedArgument => Element)` and already have it for `Future`, `Either`, etc. So it isn't removing "outer" or "inner" thing as much as converting "2 outer layers" to "single layer"

Comment: @Dima Thanks. I see what they meant now. The "inner grouping" applies to the first level inside the outer List( ), since with .flatten we are always dealing with a Collection(Collection( ), ..., Collection( )). Levels inside those collections don't matter. Thanks